# Why am I getting "failed to store wallet" using the official GUI wallet?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, windows

I am coming back to Monero and I immediately hit a roadblock.

I downloaded the ZIP file, verified its hash. I tried creating a wallet, wrote down the mnemonic phrase like a doofus, finally hit "create". It says "failed to store wallet".

I google the issue, everyone recommends to run the GUI as admin, which, if I am honest, is already "sus af", but I do that. I then spend a couple of minutes typing in what I wrote down to restore my wallet. "failed to store wallet" again.
I restart the GUI again as admin, this time trying to create a new wallet, I get "failed to store wallet".
I tried storing on different hard drives, it doesn't work either way. I am running Windows 10.

I honestly think that bugs like this defeat the purpose of having a fancy official GUI wallet. I feel tilted to say the least. What an embarrassment for the entire community.

Comment: Do you still have the old `.keys` file of your wallet or are you trying to restore from the 25 word mnemonic seed?

Comment: I am really just trying to create a wallet. The whole mnemonic seed thing was because I already wrote down on a sheet of paper the first one it gave me and I didn't want to redo the work.

Comment: OK. Thus, to be clear, the error is displayed when you are trying to create a new wallet, not restore an old one, correct?

Comment: Technically both? Not when using a .keys file, I don't have one to test with, but both with mnemonic phrase recovery and new wallet creation.

Comment: Do you have multiple user accounts? In that case, please try using another one.

Comment: This was literally a fresh install of the wallet. I have no accounts or wallets whatsoever.

Comment: I meant user accounts on your Windows system. Also, do you have another system that you could use?

Comment: Only one user account. I have a laptop which I don't use.

Comment: Would you mind trying to setup the GUI there?

Comment: installer is doing same thing so it wont help

Answer (score 0):

Select a diferent folders to store your wallet and the blockchain.

Comment: I tried that at the time. Didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Install the wallet using the installer not the zip. The zip in my opinion is useful for a portable Gui not a Gui to be used on the system.

Also pro tip: use KeepassX to store your seed. That way you can never lose or mistype the seed.